# Convert tabs to spaces phpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Is there easy way to convert tabs to spaces in phpStorm?
At the moment I use regex replacing \t->\s\s\s\s and was wondering if there is easy way to do this, since I work with magento and extension developers have never heard of coding standarts, 100 files with tabs...

Answer (score 133):

I assume you are talking about indents (leading spaces). If so:

- Edit | Convert Indents | To Spaces
- Edit | Convert Indents | To Tabs

For this you need to open such file and select text you want to process.

---

Alternatively: you can process a bunch of files at once via `"Code | Reformat Code..."` (will be done accordingly to your Code Style).. but that will do actual full reformat, which may not be desirable in some cases (e.g. limited formatting rules; or rules do not fork as you need (limited options; edge cases); or whatever).

Comment: Is there also a way to display whitespaces as tabs without really converting them?

Comment: @Gigala Unfortunately no.

Comment: That would have been nice :|

Comment: Any way to make a current tab convert tabs to spaces for the duration of the session. Or a specific file or file type always? would be nice.

Comment: + $15,370 per annum